# Autorefresh in MVC not working in IE but working in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I need to implement auto-refresh in one of my MVC apps, and I am having some problems with it.
When I did my auto-refresh logic using jquery.get() and partial views, it works perfectly in Chrome and Opera (latest versions), but doesn't work in IE 9. I have spent around a day trying to figure out the problem, but to no avail.

I have done a small test app , just to test the auto-refresh feature in all the browsers. I am having the same issue with this app.

I have attached the code below for the same and I would appreciate if anybody could tell me what the problem is with my code? Please let me know if you need some more information on this.

Thanks,
Abhi.

**index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<AutoRefreshInMVC.Views.ViewModels.HomeIndexModel>
@{
Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Index</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refresh() {
        $.get('/Home/_Quotes', function (result) {

            $('#refreshme').html(result);
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval("refresh();", 10000);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="refreshme">
    @Html.Partial("_Quotes", Model)
</div>
```

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<HomeIndexModel> model = new GetQuotes().GetData();

        return View(model);
    }

    private static List<HomeIndexModel> GetData()
    {
        List<HomeIndexModel> model = new GetQuotes().GetData();
        return model.OrderByDescending(i => i.Change).ToList();
    }

    public ActionResult _Quotes()
    {
        List<HomeIndexModel> model = GetData();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**_Quotes.chtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<AutoRefreshInMVC.Views.ViewModels.HomeIndexModel>
<table id="tblIndex">
<tr id="header">
    <th>
        Code
    </th>
    <th>
        LastValue
    </th>
    <th>
        CurrentValue
    </th>
    <th>
        Change
    </th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastValue)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CurrentValue)
        </td>
        <td class="Change">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Change)
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had some problems along these lines using the jquery shorthand `$.get` and `$.post` methods that turned out to be related to caching.

Try replacing your `$.get` with the equivalent `$.ajax` with caching disabled i.e.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/Home/_Quotes',
  success: function (result) {
              $('#refreshme').html(result);
           },
  cache: false
});
```

Answer (score 2):

setInterval should look like this:

```
setInterval(refresh(), 10000);
```

Also, be aware that your call may be cached, so you may want to place an OutputCache attribute on your _Quotes method.

Comment: Thanks Mystere Man for your response. I wanted to accept your answer too, but StanK's answer worked better for me. Shame that 2 answers cannot be accepted as the right answer. :-)